# Automatically aggregating points into clusters when zooming in on a map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I read `ggmap`'s documentation and while the density/contour maps look cool, I was wondering whether someone has replicated this [example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/examples/advanced_example.html). It creates clusters of points on geographic locations. I have many points to plot on the whole US map, so many that it hides other important information. I am using `ggplot` and `maps` to plot these maps. I would appreciate if someone has any examples of cluster plots as given in  this [example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/examples/advanced_example.html) or this [example](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/web-maps-api/examples/marker-clustering)

Comment: update: I played with the `stat_density2d`  stat in ggmap, and I was disappointed as I am plotting the whole US map. I wish there was a geom called `geom_cluster`

Comment: update: I followed the [marker maker javascript](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js) and created a `for loop` to compare each observation's distance from a cluster center, if the distance is less than the desired distance, then that observation is added to that cluster, else a new cluster is created. As you can see, it is hardly efficient. I have pasted the code [here](http://pastebin.com/TL81ycx9). I would appreciate your help with further optimization of this code